# How to post subcategory inside string seperated by commas in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Now I am able to post subcategory in the following way?
Now The result is

```
subcategory[] : Healthcare
subcategory[] : education
```

But I need to get this as string separated by commas?

My html code is

```
<div id="submitBox">
  <form method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
    <select id="basic" class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Your City" v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory[]" multiple>
      <option v-for="so in services" v-bind:value="so.name">{{so.name}}</option>  
   </form>
</div>
```

My vue js code is

```
<script>
submitBox = new Vue({
  el: "#submitBox",
  data: {
    subcategory: [],
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      data['subcategory'] = this.subcategory;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/post/',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          if (e.status) {
            alert("Registration Success")
          } 
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

I need to postas data

```
subcategory : healthcare,education
```

Can anybody please help me to solve the same?

Comment: `data['subcategory'] = this.subcategory.join(',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.subcategory` is an array, you can transform it to a string using [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fjoin) like this :

```js
let services = [
  {name: 'Hamburger'},
  {name: 'Sandwich'},
  {name: 'Hotdog'}
];

submitBox = new Vue({
  el: "#submitBox",
  data: {
    subcategory: [],
  },
  methods: {
    handelSubmit: function(e) {
      var vm = this;
      data = {};
      data['subcategory'] = this.subcategory.join(',');
      
      console.log(data);
      
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="submitBox">
  <form method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
    <select id="basic" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select Your City" v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory[]" multiple>
      <option v-for="so in services" v-bind:value="so.name">{{so.name}}</option>  
    </select>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to join the `subcategory` array inside a string separated by a comma `,`, just use:

```
data['subcategory'] = this.subcategory.join(',');
```

Maybe you could find useful to use as data of your jQuery `ajax` call something like:

```
data: {"subcategory": this.subcategory}
```